# How to debug crash on win10?

Tags: c++, windows-10, cygwin

I developed an app in C++ and built it with cygwin 32bit on win7. The app runs well on both 32bit and 64bit win7.

But when I copied the app together with all dependent DLLs to a win10 64bit machine, the app can start, but quickly crashed with signal 11.

On win10 it doesn't generate core file, so how to debug this kind of crash? Any idea?

Comment: Configure Windows to generatd minidump or fulldump files upon crashes and you will have your Windows core dump equivalent. Or just run the program in a debugger

Comment: Run it with gdb?

Answer (score 0):

It seems that the dependency is not compatible with win10, it is recommended to build on win10

Comment: What dependency? Cygwin/mingw compilers should be completely isolated from the rest of the system, so it shouldn't matter where you build, I think?